# Borrowed value does not live enough?

Tags: rust, hyper

This is the continuation of [`RefCell<std::string::String>` cannot be shared between threads safely?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67877287/refcellstdstringstring-cannot-be-shared-between-threads-safely), made a new Q for better presentation.

I made a minimal `main` with a Mutex, but now `test_for_closure` does `not live long enough` and is `dropped here while still borrowed`. What a ride! :)

Rust playground link: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=7bf56545350624e75aafa10524ea59ff

```rs
use std::{convert::Infallible, net::SocketAddr};
use std::sync::{Arc, Mutex};

use hyper::{Body, Request, Response, Server, Version};
use hyper::{Method, StatusCode};
use hyper::service::{make_service_fn, service_fn};
// use tokio::sync::Mutex;

#[tokio::main]
use std::{convert::Infallible, net::SocketAddr};
use std::sync::{Arc, Mutex};

use hyper::{Body, Request, Response, Server, Version};
use hyper::service::{make_service_fn, service_fn};

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {
    let mut test: Arc<Mutex<String>> = Arc::new(Mutex::from("Foo".to_string()));
    let mut test_for_closure = Arc::clone(&test);

    let addr = SocketAddr::from(([127, 0, 0, 1], 4321));

    let make_svc = make_service_fn(|_conn| async {
        Ok::<_, Infallible>(service_fn(|req: Request<Body>| async move {
            if req.version() == Version::HTTP_11 {
                let foo = test_for_closure.lock().unwrap();
                Ok(Response::new(Body::from(foo.as_str())))
            } else {
                Err("not HTTP/1.1, abort connection")
            }
        }))
    });

    let server = Server::bind(&addr).serve(make_svc);

    if let Err(e) = server.await {
        eprintln!("server error: {}", e);
    }

    Ok(())
}
```

[image]

How can this be addressed, considering that we will need to be able to modify the Arc's value eventually in main but still have `hyper` send back the "current" value on an HTTP response?

Comment: Please paste the error as text surrounded by triple backticks. A screenshot of your IDE is not searchable, is not editable, and can be hard to read for people with different font sizes, or on mobile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two issues, first of all, `Body` only implements `From<&'static str>` but the given `&str` is bound to the lifetime on the `MutexGuard`, therefore the `Body::from` call fails with a lifetime error. You can work around this via `foo.clone()`.

The second issue is about the multiple nested scopes which would require additional `clone()`s on the `Arc<Mutex<String>>` and `move` on the `service_fn` closure. The following compiles:

```
use std::sync::{Arc, Mutex};
use std::{convert::Infallible, net::SocketAddr};

use hyper::service::{make_service_fn, service_fn};
use hyper::{Body, Request, Response, Server, Version};

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {
    let test: Arc<Mutex<String>> = Arc::new(Mutex::from("Foo".to_string()));

    let addr = SocketAddr::from(([127, 0, 0, 1], 4321));

    let make_svc = make_service_fn(|_conn| {
        let test_for_closure = test.clone();
        let svc_fn = service_fn(move |req: Request<Body>| {
            let test_for_closure = test_for_closure.clone();
            async move {
                if req.version() == Version::HTTP_11 {
                    let foo = test_for_closure.lock().unwrap();
                    Ok(Response::new(Body::from(foo.clone())))
                } else {
                    Err("not HTTP/1.1, abort connection")
                }
            }
        });
        async move { Ok::<_, Infallible>(svc_fn) }
    });

    let server = Server::bind(&addr).serve(make_svc);

    // change the value at will:
    let mut guard = test.lock().unwrap();
    *guard = "Bar".into();
    drop(guard);

    if let Err(e) = server.await {
        eprintln!("server error: {}", e);
    }

    Ok(())
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=f360471a10e56b4a69076c08ef92280e)

Comment: Wow, so many things I was still missing. Thank you very much for the explanation!