# How to correctly read a string value from an outer scope within an async closure for Hyper in Rust

Tags: asynchronous, rust, closures, rust-tokio, hyper

I'm trying to learn Rust, and trying to write some extremely simple web server code to do so.

I thought I had a good idea of the basics of lifetimes & borrowing in simple code, but I'm finding that either I'm missing a basic technique somewhere, or what I thought was a simple case is actually much more complicated for some reason.

What I'm essentially trying to do is this:

```rust
use std::env;
use std::convert::Infallible;
use std::net::SocketAddr;
use hyper::{Body, Request, Response, Server};
use hyper::service::{make_service_fn, service_fn};

// A demo web server: takes a message on the command-line, then
// serves it back to incoming requests.

#[tokio::main]
pub async fn main() {
    let args: Vec<String> = env::args().collect();
    let message = format!("Arguments were: {:?}", &args[1..]);
    serve_message(message).await;
}

pub async fn serve_message(message: String) {
    let addr = SocketAddr::from(([127, 0, 0, 1], 3000));

    let make_svc = make_service_fn(|_conn| {
        async move {
            Ok::<_, Infallible>(service_fn(move |_: Request<Body>| async move {
                Ok::<_, Infallible>(
                    Response::new(Body::from(message))
                )
            }))
        }
    });

    let server = Server::bind(&addr).serve(make_svc);

    if let Err(e) = server.await {
        eprintln!("server error: {}", e);
    }
}
```

This fails to compile with:

```
error[E0507]: cannot move out of `message`, a captured variable in an `FnMut` closure
  --> src/main.rs:22:68
   |
17 |   pub async fn serve_message(message: String) {
   |                              ------- captured outer variable
...
22 |               Ok::<_, Infallible>(service_fn(move |_: Request<Body>| async move {
   |  ____________________________________________-----------------------_^
   | |                                            |
   | |                                            captured by this `FnMut` closure
23 | |                 Ok::<_, Infallible>(
24 | |                     Response::new(Body::from(message))
   | |                                              -------
   | |                                              |
   | |                                              variable moved due to use in generator
   | |                                              move occurs because `message` has type `String`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
25 | |                 )
26 | |             }))
   | |_____________^ move out of `message` occurs here

error[E0507]: cannot move out of `message`, a captured variable in an `FnMut` closure
  --> src/main.rs:21:9
   |
17 |   pub async fn serve_message(message: String) {
   |                              ------- captured outer variable
...
20 |       let make_svc = make_service_fn(|_conn| {
   |                                      ------- captured by this `FnMut` closure
21 | /         async move {
22 | |             Ok::<_, Infallible>(service_fn(move |_: Request<Body>| async move {
23 | |                 Ok::<_, Infallible>(
24 | |                     Response::new(Body::from(message))
   | |                                              -------
   | |                                              |
   | |                                              variable moved due to use in generator
   | |                                              move occurs because `message` has type `String`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
25 | |                 )
26 | |             }))
27 | |         }
   | |_________^ move out of `message` occurs here
```

I've tried a wide variety of more complex modifications of this, with cloning, ARCs, state into a struct with a handle impl, and lots of other approaches, but I'm struggling and each of them seems to bring me back to the same fundamental problem above. I'm clearly missing something essential about how async, closures & ownership interact, and the tools to manage that. I have seen [How to re-use a value from the outer scope inside a closure in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67860385/how-to-re-use-a-value-from-the-outer-scope-inside-a-closure-in-rust) which is similar, but the only answer's example is a simpler demo that doesn't clearly translate to the larger problem - just adding `.clone()` as suggested everywhere doesn't seem sufficient for this case.

The part I find most confusing is that this is extremely similar to one of Hyper's own examples: https://docs.rs/hyper/latest/hyper/service/fn.make_service_fn.html#example. But that example doesn't seem to hit any issues, while this does.

What's the correct & idiomatic way to do this, why does it work, and what's the difference between this and that Hyper example case? Beginner-level explanations much appreciated.

Comment: Cloning/`Arc` should work. How did you try it?

Comment: @ChayimFriedman, ok that's a useful clue! I've tried 10s of different ways though, I'm just very much out of my depth and not sure how they're meant to be used. All examples I can find are trivial and don't obviously map to slightly trickier cases like this for me. Can you share an example of how you'd use them in this scenario, and explain why?

Comment: I prefer that you will share your attempts and then I will explain what went wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason that you are getting this error is that the `message` string is being moved into the closure that you pass to `service_fn`. In Rust, each value has a unique owner, and moving a value transfers its ownership. Once a value has been moved, it can no longer be used from the original location. See "[Ownership and moves](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/scope/move.html)"

However, in your case, you want to use the `message` string in multiple responses, which means you need to share it between multiple closures. This is where [`Arc` (Atomic Reference Counting)](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/std/arc.html?highlight=arc#arc) comes in handy.
An `Arc<T>` is a thread-safe reference-counted pointer that allows shared read access to a value of type `T`. It can be cloned to create a new pointer to the same value, increasing the reference count.

You can update your `serve_message` function to wrap the `message` in an `Arc` and then clone it for each request [like this (playground)](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=ff84ec07e105ad471eb5ec2e69a95626):

```rust
use bytes::Bytes;
use hyper::{
    service::{make_service_fn, service_fn},
    Body, Error as HyperError, Request, Response, Server,
};
use std::convert::Infallible;
use std::net::SocketAddr;
use std::sync::Arc;

pub async fn serve_message(message: String) {
    let addr = SocketAddr::from(([127, 0, 0, 1], 3000));

    let message = Arc::new(Bytes::from(message));

    let make_svc = make_service_fn(move |_conn| {
        let message = Arc::clone(&message);
        async {
            Ok::<_, Infallible>(service_fn(move |_: Request<Body>| {
                let message = Bytes::copy_from_slice(&*Arc::clone(&message));
                async move { Ok::<_, HyperError>(Response::new(Body::from(message))) }
            }))
        }
    });

    let server = Server::bind(&addr).serve(make_svc);

    if let Err(e) = server.await {
        eprintln!("server error: {}", e);
    }
}
```

The way it works is:

- `Arc::new(message)` creates a new `Arc` that owns the `message`. This is the only `Arc` that directly owns the `message`.
- Each time `make_service_fn` is called, it clones the `Arc` (not the `message` itself), which increases the reference count but does not move the `message`.
- Inside `service_fn`, we again clone the `Arc` for each request. This allows each request to have a reference to the `message` without taking ownership.
- Finally, `Response::new(Body::from((*Arc::clone(&message)).clone()))` clones the `Arc` one more time to use the `message` in the response. This does not move the `message` and allows it to be used in subsequent responses.

Regarding the last point:

The code `Response::new(Body::from(Arc::clone(&message).to_string()))` would work as well, but there is a key difference to keep in mind.

When you use `Arc::clone(&message).to_string()`, you are creating a new `String` for every request. This can be inefficient if the `message` is large or if there are a lot of requests, because it involves allocating memory for a new `String` each time.

Instead, `let message = Bytes::copy_from_slice(&*Arc::clone(&message))` is of type `Bytes`.

In this code, we're using `Bytes::copy_from_slice(&*Arc::clone(&message))` to create a new `Bytes` instance from the shared `Bytes` for each request.
This is less efficient than sharing the `Bytes` directly (as we would ideally like to do), but it avoids the borrowing errors you were encountering earlier.

The breakdown is:

- `Arc::clone(&message)` creates a new `Arc` that points to the same `Bytes` value that `message` points to. The type of `Arc::clone(&message)` is `Arc<Bytes>`.
- `&*Arc::clone(&message)` dereferences the `Arc<Bytes>` to get a reference to the `Bytes` value it points to. The type of `&*Arc::clone(&message)` is `&Bytes`.
- `Bytes::copy_from_slice(&*Arc::clone(&message))` creates a new `Bytes` value that contains the same byte sequence as the `Bytes` value `message` points to. The type of `Bytes::copy_from_slice(&*Arc::clone(&message))` is `Bytes`.

The `Bytes::copy_from_slice` function expects a reference to a byte slice (`&[u8]`), and `&Bytes` can be used as `&[u8]` because `Bytes` implements `Deref<Target=[u8]>`.

So the overall effect of `Bytes::copy_from_slice(&*Arc::clone(&message))` is to create a new `Bytes` value that contains a copy of the bytes from the original `Bytes` value, allowing it to be used independently in the response body.

---

Dereferencing `Arc<Bytes>` to get a `Bytes` reference (`&Bytes`) doesn't work is because [`Body::from`](https://docs.rs/hyper/0.14.26/hyper/body/struct.Body.html#impl-From%3CBytes%3E-for-Body) doesn't accept a `&Bytes` reference as a parameter.
While Rust's `From` trait often does work with references, in this case, the `From` trait is only implemented for the owned `Bytes` type and not for a reference to `Bytes`.

- `Body::from` consumes its argument. It takes ownership of the provided value.
- When you dereference `Arc<Bytes>`, you get a `&Bytes` (a reference to `Bytes`), not an owned `Bytes`.
- A `&Bytes` is not the same thing as `Bytes`. They are different types. The former is a reference to a `Bytes` value, the latter is an *owned* `Bytes` value.
- Because `Body::from` is not implemented for `&Bytes`, you can't pass a `&Bytes` to `Body::from`.

---

The [Hyper example you linked](https://docs.rs/hyper/latest/hyper/service/fn.make_service_fn.html#example) creates an HTTP response with a body of type `hyper::Body::empty()`, which does not involve any borrowing from the outer scope.

In your code, you are trying to use a `String` (`message`) from the outer scope inside your service function, which leads to the borrowing issues you are encountering.

Your use case is different from the Hyper example because you want to share an owned `String` between multiple closures, which requires the use of `Arc` as explained above. The `Arc` allows multiple closures to have a read-only reference to the same `String` without taking ownership of it.

Comment: Phew, thank you, that's _extremely_ helpful! There was still one tiny bug here, as the inner-most `Arc::clone(&message)` needs a `.to_string()`, but otherwise that all makes sense and it finally works now .

Comment: @TimPerry But I thought the `Body::from` function in Hyper  can accept anything that can be viewed as a byte slice `(&[u8])`, and `Arc<String>` satisfies that requirement because String itself implements `AsRef<[u8]>`.

So when you do `Body::from(Arc::clone(&message))`, it should work because it can view the `Arc<String>` as a byte slice.

Comment: No idea I'm afraid! In my case I get `the trait From<Arc<String>> is not implemented for Body` unless I use `Arc::clone(&message).to_string()` in there. Using the latest Hyper release - 0.14.26.

Comment: @TimPerry OK, I have updated the code, but using Byte instead of to_string(), to avoid creating a new `String` for every request.

Comment: That change all sounds sensible, but the code still has the same issue: `the trait From<Arc<bytes::Bytes>> is not implemented for Body`. For Bytes 1 + Hyper 0.14.26.

Comment: @TimPerry Got it. After reading [the source code](https://docs.rs/hyper/0.14.26/src/hyper/body/body.rs.html#487-496), and playing with [the playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=ff84ec07e105ad471eb5ec2e69a95626), I believe my latest edit (with updated code and updated explanations) should work.